# Alternative query string formats

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm currently building a web app with Codeigniter. I noticed their documentation favors segmented URLs over query strings which makes sense since they're so much easier to read and look nicer. I was also browsing threadless.com the other day and really liked the way they formatted their queries:

Normally, a query would look like this:

```
http://www.threadless.com/catalog/index.php?type=guys&view=25&size=3xl
```

But Threadless uses this format:

```
http://www.threadless.com/catalog/type,guys/view,25/size,3xl
```

How do they get that format? Does it involve the .htaccess? Does that format play nice with Codeigniter or would it involve a custom function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something similar where you can have.

```
http://www.threadless.com/catalog/type/guys/view/25/size/3x1
```

To do so, you'd have a controller function like:

```
class Catalog extends CI_Controller {
    function catalog()
    {
        $params = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(3);
    }
}
```

Which would output something like:

```
Array
(
    [type] => 'guys'
    [view] => 25
    [size] => '3x1'
)
```

If you want the commas, you'd want to touch .htaccess to rewrite all "," into "/".

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([^\,]*)\,(.*)$
RewriteRule .* %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to rewrite the URL without making it visible in the browser? Right now it converts the comma to a slash, but it would be awesome if the comma could stay in the URL and still function as a slash.

Comment: I believe if you remove `R=301` that should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It's mod_rewrite in your .htaccess

http://statichtml.com/2010/mod-rewrite-baseon-on-query-string.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache, then it would involve either .htaccess, .htdocs, or httpd.conf (there are multiple methods). The key is to set it so that a file named "catalog" is parsed as a .php file. Then, everything after the filename (`/type,guys/view,25/size,3xl`) is passed to the script as `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`, which you'd parse yourself.

Not sure how CodeIgniter works exactly or whether it has features to do this a different way.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the way that CodeIgniter usually does things, but there is help in http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

You'll need to edit `/application/config/routing.php`

Comment: I agree : It's better to stick with default Routing system of CodeIgniter